# How to remove last digits from numbers in the middle of a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string like this:

```
var string = "value1=12345&value2=3210&value3=..."
```

I want to remove two last digits of value1 and value2, so the resulting string is:

```
string = "value1=123&value2=32&value3=..."
```

I could split the string on `&`, loop over items and remove two last chars if the item begins with value1 or value2, then join the items with `&`. But how to do it as short as possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of number? base 2, 16, or 10? I see strings here not really numbers

Comment: Can you always expect an `&` to immediately precede `value2` and `value3`?

Comment: Yes, the `&` is always a separator.

Comment: Split, modify, and join seems like the cleanest way to do it. Is “short” really so valuable?

Comment: Yes, because it will be inside a closure, so it should fit in a one line for the sake of readability.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. Also, here’s something shortish in Firefox `s.split('&').map(x=>let([k,v]=x.split('='))~keys.indexOf(k)?x.slice(0,-2):x).join('&')`.

Comment: I like elegant, minimalistic solutions. Now it makes sense? ;)

Comment: I find that tricky one-liners are often harder for other devs to decipher when reading my code. It's usually more considerate to be explicit in your logic except where performance outweighs legibility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string = string.replace(/(value[12]=\d*)\d{2}/g, '$1');
```

The regular expression matches `value1=` or `value2=`, followed by a sequence of digits. The capture group gets everything until the last 2 digits. Then we replace the match with the capture group, so the last 2 digits get removed.

Answer (score 3):

Based off the **given** string, you could use Positive Lookahead here to remove the last two digits.

```
var r = "value1=12345&value2=3210&value3=...".replace(/\d{2}(?=&)/g, '');
console.log(r); //=> "value1=123&value2=32&value3=..."
```

If  `&` does not always follow in the string and you strictly want to change `value1` and `value2`...

```
var r = "value1=12345&value2=3210&value3=...".replace(/(value[12]=\d*)\d{2}/g, '$1');
console.log(r); //=> "value1=123&value2=32&value3=..."
```

Comment: This solution could modify other values besides `value1` and `value2`.

Comment: _I_ don't care what values get changed, but thanks for taking the time to copy Barmar's answer verbatim into your own.

Comment: Actually I didn't copy any answer, it's just the way you would write the expression for what you exactly want to do.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about positive lookahead.